# Notify the comment's target user when a comment is removed for cause

Tags: discussion, feature-request

One of problems discussed in the aftermath of the *Blog Post Of Welcomness* was the fact that new users faced with rude comments ("At such a level of knowledge you should not call yourself a developer") leave and never come back.

Would it help if SO notified the comment's target that the comment has been deleted after being flagged? I use "after being flagged" advisedly here - even self-deleted comment would mean something if it was flagged as rude before being deleted.

This could give SO a second chance with someone who encounters a bad side of our community...

Some clarifications:

This is oriented towards brand new users who may not know about flagging or watching profile. The goal is to show the user that the community is dealing with rudeness.

"The target" in this case would be everyone who originally got notified about the comment: the question's owner, the answer's owner and anyone tagged by @name tag.

Comment: Note: Currently you can find this if you go looking for your helpful flags on your profile, *if* you were the one who flagged the comment to begin with. A notification probably wouldn't hurt, particularly for newer users who aren't inundated with notification noise yet.

Comment: One problem is that the “target” sometimes isn’t the post owner, but some other commenter. Something to consider?

Comment: It may help.... But if the user is gone 'never to return'... That won't do much good :/.  It will surely help the ones that do stick around to see more prominently that the reception they got was an anomaly, that other users disagreed with it, and that because of that it was removed

Comment: @Patrice If the user created an account and provide e-mail, we could send an e-mail (would that be spamming?) If not, not much can be done :(

Comment: @Arkadiy yeah that is likely the best we can do. I'd prefer an SO where first posts aren't met with comments worthy of a flag.. but this won't be soon unfortunately. In the meantime I think your idea has merit

Comment: I have a cunning plan to solve the unwelcome comments issue.  Watch this space..

Comment: I have suggested this elsewhere as well. But more and more I’m tending towards the (likely extremely unpopular) opinion that there are just way too many comments on questions, period. I would be curious to see SO run for a few days with Q comments turned off entirely. (I realize that’s extreme, I’m just curious how awkward that would be, really.)

Comment: Do you mean "deleted after being flagged *as rude or abusive*"? Because I'm not sure anyone cares that, say, a comment suggesting you fix something in your post is deleted once the improvements are made. (In fact, I think being notified of this type of deletion would just be infuriating.)

Comment: @Laurel Yes, it should be limited to "rude and abusive" and "In need for intervention", sure

Comment: @joran If initial question quality was routinely high, trying things without comments might be reasonable. Unfortunately, at lest for the questions I see, the vast majority need some type of improvement that requires communicating with the OP. Without comments, that would be … inconvenient to accomplish. Thus, with comments turned off, most of those questions would languish in a poor and often (usually?) unanswerable state.

Comment: @Makyen Part of my point in suggesting provocative things like that regarding comments is to try to prompt people to think about whether improving questions via some communication with the OP absolutely _requires_ the current comment UI. I suspect it does not, if we got creative. Obviously ditching comments and not replacing it with anything would be bad...but I wish people would stop assuming that the _only_ way to interact with the OP is a free entry text box.

Answer (score 7):

Let's extend this a bit: what if the site had a better means of notifying you when your flags were marked as being helpful? Warnings were added when people were flagging incorrectly, and those have made people very aware of declined flags, but maybe more could be done to show how helpful flags have led to desired outcomes?

One of the most powerful motivators for continuing to perform moderation-related actions is feeling like you're making a difference. As a user, when I went back to my flags and saw that non-answers I'd flagged were deleted, I became a lot more motivated to flag these. However, that required first discovering how I could track my accepted / declined flags and manually checking in on them. Many people don't get that far, given how non-obvious it is that you have to click on your helpful flag count to see a breakdown.

Rude comments, once flagged, don't last long. It's getting people to identify and flag them to begin with that's the important part. A longer-term solution might be some kind of comment review queue, similar to current post review queues. In the near term, though, if people saw their flags being acted on quickly I bet we'd get more people actively flagging rude comments.

How could positive outcomes of flags be better presented to a new user? One way might be an inbox notification after your first helpful (or even declined) flag, thanking the user for flagging and showing them how they can get to a list of their pending and reviewed flags.

Another might be to break out flags from the somewhat-hidden clickable link in your profile to a dedicated "flags" tab next to "responses" in your profile. This would only be viewable by the user, and would either consist of the current flag breakdown or a chronological list of handled flags. As new flags are handled, a little blue icon could appear next to the tab (like it does for new responses) and let you know that you could review the results. Whether or not a post was deleted in response to a flag could be visible there.

Again, the site has mechanisms in place for warning people about bad flagging patterns, what about highlighting and encouraging good ones?

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but my suggestion was somewhat orthogonal to yours. You're talking about improving the experience of the person who flagged a comment. I am proposing to improve the experience of the person who was the target of the comment, but not necessarily the flagger. The reasoning is that the new user may not know how to flag, but would benefit from the knowledge that someone else flagged.

Comment: Maybe I’m confused but I thought the question was more about communication with the owner of a Q that received a rude comment, rather than the flagger.

Comment: @Arkadiy - True, I guess the idea of some kind of notification on a positive action got me thinking about what else could be done for the parties involved. Just wanted to throw an idea out there.

Comment: Why not both, @Arkadiy? And in some cases, the same user _might be_ both flagger and OP. Surely that happens even with newer users. The "flag" option exists on so many sites/forums that it's probably easy for newer users to understand what it means. If they don't, then with your idea they still get notification. If they _do,_ then they both get notification it was removed, _and_ notification that they handled it correctly by flagging.

Comment: @Kendra: Sure, let's embrace the healing power of "and".